# Make payment method visible only in admin only

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, payment-methods

I would like to make the Purchase Order method of payment accessible only in admin order creation, and not visible in the front end checkout process.I am using the rwd theme and do not program so please be clear which files I need to amend and where if possible. Thank you.

Comment: do you want to create an order using payment method in admin area?

Answer (score 1):

Actually not that difficult to achieve.

Payment methods models contain certain properties, which determine their functionality.

Have a look at `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` and you can get a full list of properties, and the defaults.

The three of interest will be:

```
 protected $_canUseInternal             
 protected $_canUseCheckout              
 protected $_canUseForMultishipping
```

canUseInternal = admin

So, to enable/disable a payment method for the area, simply set the appropriate flag.

A mini tutorial, since you mention you are not a developer:

Install `n98-magerun`

In the root of the site run the command:

`n98-magerun.phar dev:module:create --add-all ProxiBlue AdminOnlyPayments community`

This will create the extension base folder structure, located here: `/app/code/community/ProxiBlue/AdminOnlyPayments`

Edit the file: `/app/code/community/ProxiBlue/AdminOnlyPayments/etc/config.xml`

and change this section:

```
<models>
        <proxiblue_adminonlypayments>
            <class>ProxiBlue_AdminOnlyPayments_Model</class>
        </proxiblue_adminonlypayments>
    </models>
```

to

```
<models>
   <proxiblue_adminonlypayments>
     <class>ProxiBlue_AdminOnlyPayments_Model</class>
   </proxiblue_adminonlypayments>
<payment>
 <rewrite>
              <method_purchaseorder>ProxiBlue_AdminOnlyPayments_Model_Method_Purchaseorder</method_purchaseorder>
 </rewrite>
</payment>
```

Create the file
`/app/code/community/ProxiBlue/AdminOnlyPayments/Model/Method/Purchaseorder.php`

and place the following contents:

```
class ProxiBlue_AdminOnlyPayments_Model_Method_Purchaseorder extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Purchaseorder
{

    protected $_canUseInternal              = true;
    protected $_canUseCheckout              = false; 
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false;

}
```

Hope that helps